# When I use scoped css in Vue.js, "this" becomes undefined in template

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, scope, this

When I set the css style of my vue component in scoped, I no longer have access to "this" in the template but in my script yes.
I get the following error message:
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined"
I need it because I am using the store see sample code.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
export default ({
    name: "ModelSelect",
    computed: {
      modelList: {
        get () {
          return this.$store.state.identification.modelList
        }
      },
      model: {
        get () {
          return this.$store.state.identification.model.id
        },
        set (value) {
          this.$store.dispatch('identification/updateModel', value)
        }
      },
    },
    updated() {
      this.$emit('scrollToNext')
    }
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="form-select-section mb-5 border p-4" v-if="modelList.length > 0 && this.$store.state.identification.brand.id">
    <span class="text-gray-700 mb-3 block">Choix du modèle</span>
    <ul class="select-group grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-5 xl:grid-cols-8 gap-4">
      <li class="select-item" v-for="modelItem in modelList" :key="modelItem.attributes.name+modelItem.id">
        <input type="radio" name="model" :value="modelItem.id" v-model="model" :id="modelItem.attributes.name+modelItem.id" class="hidden">
        <label :for="modelItem.attributes.name+modelItem.id" class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-center">
          <span class="mt-1">{{modelItem.attributes.name}}</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .select-item {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `this` in your template anyway. Just use `v-if="modelList.length > 0 && $store.state.identification.brand.id"`

Comment: Indeed it works, it seemed to me to have tested it yet. Thank you very much Phil and sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: It's a common enough error for me to have a canned response so no, not stupid at all